# how to get data in controller on ci3

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

how to get data in controller using codeigniter 3 framework

i have code in ci3 controller like this:

```
public function ajax_list()
{
$list = $this->thesis_title->get_datatables();
$data = array();
$no = $_POST['start'];
$text1 = "Detection of student assignments based on document.";
$text2 ="test program simple levenshtein distance";
$distance=levenshtein($text1, $text2);

foreach ($list as $text_title) {
$no++;
$row = array();
$row[] = $no;
$row[] = $title_text->id_title;
$row[] = $title_text->title;
$row[] = $distance;

$data[] = $row;
}
$output = array(
"draw" => $_POST['draw'],
"recordsTotal" => $this->title_thesis->count_all(),
"recordsFiltered" => $this->title_thesis->count_filtered(),
"data" => $data,
);
//output to json format
echo json_encode($output);
}
```

what I want to do is retrieve the title data from the database and assign the value to the $text1 variable

Comment: please make our code example clearer, are there any errors? how about `$no++`, `$no`is nowhere defined; we don't know about `$text1` (is it important to the example?). and most of all: what does *"how to get data in controller on ci3"* mean? is this controller function called via Ajax?

Comment: Looks a general question for Google. You might have found many answers. Like how to get data from database in codeigniter 3. It may help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831224/display-data-from-database-using-codeigniter )

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the title in your database with **foreach** loop,

```
public function ajax_list()
{
   $list = $this->thesis_title->get_datatables();
   
   foreach($list as $l){
      $title = $l->title //<------------(your title column at database);
   }

   $data = array();
   $no = $_POST['start'];
   $text1 = $title; //<-------inserting result of looping in the variable text1
   $text2 ="test program simple levenshtein distance";
   $distance=levenshtein($text1, $text2);

   foreach ($list as $text_title) {
   $no++;
   $row = array();
   $row[] = $no;
   $row[] = $title_text->id_title;
   $row[] = $title_text->title;
   $row[] = $distance;

   $data[] = $row;
}
$output = array(
"draw" => $_POST['draw'],
"recordsTotal" => $this->title_thesis->count_all(),
"recordsFiltered" => $this->title_thesis->count_filtered(),
"data" => $data,
);
//output to json format
echo json_encode($output);
}`
```